# Python----Indentation Error

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why it's giving me expected an indented block error? I thought I did it correctly.

```
    for j in range(1,size[0]-1): 
         if (seq1[j]=='A'):  #Go vertical   seq1[i]==seq2[j]   
                        temp_d=dy_matrix[i-1][j-1]+sub_matrix[0][0]  #AA match
                 temp_h=dy_matrix[i][j-1]+g 
    #Compare!!! temp_d,  temp_h, temp_v


    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Just Learn [Python](https://www.python.org/).

Comment: Use any rich IDE to edit scripts to avoid such types of errors.

Comment: Thank you!!!!It all works now. This is not the first time I use python but the first time I ran into indentation problem. I used whatever indent before and had no problems, but not this time. And I learned that tab equals 4 spaces as well in your answer. So, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you have a problem with your indentation.

```
for j in range(1,size[0]-1): 
    if (seq1[j]=='A'):  #Go vertical   seq1[i]==seq2[j]   
        temp_d=dy_matrix[i-1][j-1]+sub_matrix[0][0]  #AA match
        temp_h=dy_matrix[i][j-1]+g
```

Make each indentation four spaces or one tab and your code should work.

Edit: As Matthias mentioned, spaces are the preferred solution here.

Comment: According to the 'Style Guide for Python Code' [spaces are preferred](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Answer (score 1):

This line in your code:

```
if (seq1[j]=='A'):  #Go vertical   seq1[i]==seq2[j]
```

has a mix of tab and space characters.

Sometimes even though you maintain the indentation correctly visually, it is important to check if all of the indentation characters are the same (all spaces or all tabs)

Answer (score 1):

```
for j in range(1,size[0]-1): 
    if (seq1[j]=='A'):  #Go vertical   seq1[i]==seq2[j]   
        temp_d=dy_matrix[i-1][j-1]+sub_matrix[0][0]  #AA match
        temp_h=dy_matrix[i][j-1]+g
```